# Problem with jquery or jquery ui (animating color)

Tags: 7, javascript

I have [found](http://forrst.com/posts/Endlessly_Looping_Background_Color_jQuery_Functi-ey7) a jquery code which animates colors. I made a fiddle from it (after minor change), and it's working perfectly on jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/kFuzp/

Unfortunately, it's not working on my Drupal site. I have JQuery Update module and updated to 1.8, using jQuery CDN. The code (as in jsfiddle) is inserted using `drupal_add_js ($script1, 'inline')` in `mytheme_preprocess_page()`. When I debug the code in Chrome, it just runs (I can observe how the color_index changes etc using breakpoints). But the `<p>` background color is always white.

By the way, when I change the animation property to `{ opacity: color_index/7 }` then the opacity animation is working (slowly) both in jsfiddle and in Drupal.

Why it's not working in Drupal and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also having the same problem once, I was doing an animation in color change. It was not working for me in Drupal, however for some reason I do not know the color change animation was working when I was logged in as administrator(with [admin_menu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) installed), while as authenticated and anonymous user it was not working.

I used [jQuery.Color()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin and it worked for me. Its written in [jQuery.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) documentation:

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height,
>   or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the
>   jQuery.Color() plugin is used). Property values are treated as a
>   number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be
>   specified where applicable.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're having a problem with your jQuery selector.

Are you using changing the properties for all paragraphs? Or just a particular one? Or a class?

Below are the selectors for each option respectively:

```
$("p")...

$("p#theIdofTheParagraph")...

$("p.theClassofTheParagraphs")...
```